# How to provide initial state for a single multireducer sub-slice

Tags: javascript, redux

My project uses [multireducer](https://github.com/erikras/multireducer) to maintain many instances of the same reducer.
My store is created using something like this:

```
const initialState = {};

export default createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({   
    foo: fooReducer,
    sorting: multireducer({
        sorterA: tableSorterReducer,
        sorterB: tableSorterReducer,
    }),
}), initialState);
```

Now, I need to add an initial state for `sorterB`.
If I add the following...

```
const initialState = {
    sorting: {
        sorterB: { key: 'foo', order: 'asc' }
    }
};
```

... then `sorterA` is not created in the store at all, since it is not included in the initial value of `sorting`.

So how can I specifiy an initial state for only part of a multireducer?

Answer (score 1):

Going over the documentation helped me figure out a solution.

> All reducers are passed undefined on initialization, so they should be written such that when given undefined, some value should be returned.

- [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html)

So all I need to do is make sure that my reducer function returns the  expected initial state when it receives `undefined`!

Here's what I came up with:

```
export default createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers({   
    foo: fooReducer,
    sorting: multireducer({
        sorterA: tableSorterReducer,
        sorterB: (state = { key: 'foo', order: 'asc' }, action) => 
            tableSorterReducer(state, action),
    }),
}));
```

Of course, `tableSorterReducer` defines it's own `initialState`, but I'm overriding that here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually go with it.

Configuring store:

```
export default function configureStore(preloadedState){
    let defaultStates = {
        user: {
            isLoggedIn: preloadedState.isLoggedIn,
        }
        // preloadedState contains values from server, in order to hydrate store
    };

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        defaultStates,
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            loggerMiddleware
        )
    )
}
```

And a reducer example:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isLoggedIn: false
};

export default function user(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_LOGGED_IN:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoggedIn: true
            });
        case USER_LOGGED_OUT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoggedIn: false
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are suggesting looks like the standard, well-documented method of supplying an initial state for a *slice* of the store.
This answer does not address the question, which is about supplying an initial value for only _part_ of a nested slice.

Comment: By providing a default state for each reducer you should be able to provide an initial state for every part of any nested slice you want. You can format the default object provided to your liking.

Comment: Yeah, that's what led me to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878777/507240 thanks!